# Spring Data JPA: Why does saving this entity work as intended (i.e. parent is thankfully not overwritten)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've been follow the Spring Boot Quick Start tutorial on Youtube.

On this particular [video](https://youtu.be/bEKt7LLEvb0?t=9m5s) in the playlist, I discovered something very peculiar.

*Snippet from CourseController.java*

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/topics/{topicId}/courses")
public void addCourse(@RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable String topicId){
    course.setTopic(new Topic(topicId,"",""));
    courseService.addCourse(course);
}
```

*Snippet from CourseService.java*

```
    public void addCourse(Course Course){
    coursesRepository.save(Course);
}
```

At first, I thought that this method would be further changed down the line as I was skeptical of it working in this state.

However, when I ran the application, all is well (i.e. the new Course entity object is successfully parented to an existing Topic entity object) even though that method had remained unchanged from what I posted.

**I want to ask how come the existing values of the parent entity, Topic, isn't overwritten as I had initially assumed?**

I've consulted the Hibernate documentation and Spring Data JPA documentation but can't find a straightforward explanation for why no unintended operations are happen to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as it turns out it is the cascade operations of @ManyToOne.

As long as I don't set cascade parameter in the annotation, it won't have adverse side-effects.